# How to include session log file

Tags: php, session, cookies, logging

[php]

```
$filename = "./logs/".$_SESSION['uniqueID'].".php" ; // output 4b1e7b3489549.php

$data = "bla..bla..\n";

$data = stripcslashes($data);

/* Writing file configurations */
    $buat = fopen($filename, "w+");
    fwrite($buat, "$data");
    fclose($buat);
?>
```

[/php]
Now whe i call the output file from $filename (record.php) from page click.php below:
[php]

```
$filelog2 = "./logs/config.php";

    if(file_exists($filelog1)){
        require_once $filelog1;
    }else{
        require_once $filelog2;
    }

echo "$filelog1 , $filelog2";// test
?>
```

[/php]
When i go to page click.php i got Page load error in my firefox browser below, what this problem and how to fix it? thankyou...

Redirect Loop

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

The browser has stopped trying to retrieve the requested item. The site is redirecting the request in a way that will never complete.

- Have you disabled or blocked cookies required by this site?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this has to do with the code your posted. Check whether you have any `header("location:...")` commands in your code and whether they may be looping (i.e. redirecting to a page that again redirects to a page that redirects to a page).

It could also be a `.htaccess` file (or Apache configuration) containing mod_rewrite instructions with the `[R]` parameter creating an endless loop.

Comment: Ok Pekka thankyou for your suggestions, you are right man!, i little bit idiot before.... i forget to remove header("location: ./") in log file...